# How to display icon in uninstall list of programs using python cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am able to build a MSI to my application and it works fine but the icon in control panel--> uninstall a program--> my-application is missing.

[image]

How to make custom `setup.py` file to display the icon?

I tried to include the icon in the setup file as below but it is displayed only at the MyProgramMenu:

```
exe = Executable( 
    script="test.py", 
    initScript=None,
    base=base,  
    targetName="test.exe", 
    copyDependentFiles=True,
    compress=False,
    appendScriptToExe=False,
    appendScriptToLibrary=False,
    shortcutDir="MyProgramMenu",
    shortcutName=APP_NAME,
    icon="test.ico" 
)
```

I want to display the icon in the list of programs in the control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no easy and clean way using:

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

as you would basically need to do the extra step described in [Set the icon displayed in Add/Remove Programs](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912527-Set-the-icon-displayed-in-Add-Remove-Programs) which would require to patch `distutils\command\bdist_msi.py` in a probably non-generic way.

To make a more customizable installer with proper uninstall icon, you can use script-based tools such as [NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Perform only the build step with cx_Freeze:

```
python setup.py build
```

and run the installer-generating script of NSIS or any other tool you chose afterwards.

Comment: Hi @jpeg thank you very much for the response but I am new to this msi creation, could you please send some sample code or links about how to do patch or how to use nsis after creating msi file, It would be a great help if you give some clue once again thanks a lot !

Comment: @SridharSri You need to use `!define MUI_ICON` for the installer icon and `!define MUI_UNICON` for the uninstaller icon. See for example https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Sample_installation_script_for_an_application